# Is it possible to show google map popup in modal

Tags: maps, bootstrap-modal, infobox

I am attempting to find a reference to popup the info box into a modal.  My usecase is such that the Google Maps popup is a very useful navigation tool, however since it anchors clicked object it is often off screen on a mobile device.

I haven't found anything that suggests this is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was something I looked into but never went anywhere with.
Here is an example I did not create this just something I had tucked away in my bookmarks... seems to fit with what you are doing

http://www.bootply.com/106707